# How to get the four corners of a rotated image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, rotation, corner-detection

I have an image rotated with `imrotate` as follow:

```
Im_requete=imread('lena.jpg');
Im_requete_G=rgb2gray(Im_requete);
Im_requete_G_scale_rot = imresize(imrotate(Im_requete_G,-20), 1.2);
```

I'm trying to get the coordinates (x, y) of the four corners of the rotated image as illustrated in the image below (red circle represents the desired corner):

[image: Desired result]

This is my code:

```
stat = regionprops(Im_requete_G_scale_rot,'Extrema'); %extrema detection of the image.
point = stat.Extrema;
hold on
figure,imshow(Im_requete_G_scale_rot)
hold on
for i = 2:2:length(point)
    x = point(i,1);
    y = point(i,2);
    plot(x,y,'o');
    text(x,y,num2str(i),'color','r')
end
```

But the resulting coordinates are somewhere along the edges and not where I wanted them to be, as illustrated in the second image:

[image: Current, wrong result]

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: A rotation about the center and the resize of an image can be expressed using a single affine transformation. Is there any reason why you can't just use the affine transformation that corresponds to this rotation to map the corners of the image to their corresponding location in the rotated image? 

Unless this is a homework exercise, I'm not sure why you'd want to use corner detection to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I already try corner () function, but the result is not as wanted `C = corner(Im_requete_G_scale_rot,'Harris',4);
figure,
imshow(Im_requete_G_scale_rot);
hold on
plot(C(:,1), C(:,2), 'r*');`

Comment: Alex didn’t suggest you use corner detection, he suggested you compute the location of the corners given the rotation angle. This is a trivial exercise involving `cos` and `sin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a good explanation for this, but I suppose `regionprops` gets confused by the grayscale tones in the image. If we turn the rotated Lena into a `logical` array, your algorithm works properly:

```
Im_requete_G_scale_rot = logical(imresize(imrotate(Im_requete_G,-20), 1.2)); % 3rd line
```

[image]